# telescoping series

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose $a, b, c$ and $d$ are constants such that the following holds for all real numbers $x$  such that all denominators are nonzero:

\begin{align}
& \frac{14}{x(x+14)}+\frac{14}{(x+7)(x+21)}+\frac{14}{(x+14)(x+28)} \\
&+ \frac{14}{(x+21)(x+35)}+\frac{14}{(x+28)(x+42)} \\
&= \frac{a(x^2+42x+147)}{x(x+b)(x+c)(x+d)}.
\end{align}

what is the value of a+b+c+d ?

---

i tried to solve it by using regular method for telescoping series as follows
the general formula i determined is $\frac{14}{(7n+x-7)(7n+x+7)}$ which equals $\frac{1}{(7n+x-7)}-\frac{1}{(7n+x+7)}$ using technique of telescoping series by substituting with $n=1$ in the first term and $n=5$ in the second term i get  $\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x+42}$ which equals $\frac{42}{x(x+42)}$ i don't know how to go from here or did i make a mistake ?

Comment: Wait.. Solve what?

Comment: get values of a,b,c and d i will edit the question sorry

Comment: What exactly are you trying to show? My thought would be to multiply each side by the denominator of the right hand side, then argue that the result on the LHS must be polynomial, showing that the linear factors must cancel. ${x+a \over x + 21}=1$ for example.

Comment: Is there a missing $\cdots$ somewhere?

Comment: @user21820 no that the question i get from https://brilliant.org/practice/telescoping-series/?p=4

Comment: Oh yea I'm blur.. it's correct..

Comment: Just write out all the terms (don't try to apply any previously remembered formula) and you will see what went wrong.

Comment: @user21820 do you mean the general formula i determined is wrong? or you mean to write LHS ?

Comment: Each term in the original can be expressed as the difference of two simpler terms as you have shown. Just write them all out and cancel the ones that cancel.. I didn't do it myself but it would definitely give you a result with 4 linear factors in the denominator.

Answer (score 1):

i checked my answer and now i know where it went wrong thanks @user21820

$LHS=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{5}\frac{14}{(7n+x-7)(7n+x+7)}=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{5}\frac{1}{(7n+x-7)}-\frac{1}{(7n+x+7)}$

after writing down all the terms they cancel each others and only four remains

$LHS=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x+7}-\frac{1}{x+35}-\frac{1}{x+42}=\frac{70(x^2+42x+147)}{x(x+7)(x+35)(x+42)}$

$a+b+c+d=70+7+35+42=154$

Comment: You're welcome! =)

Comment: As a shortcut, once you get the LHS as a sum of fractions:
$$LHS = \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{x+7} - \frac{1}{x+35} + \frac{1}{x+42}$$
you know $b,c,d$ are $7, 35, 42$. You can determine $a$ by multiplying both sides by $x^2$ and take the limit $x \to \infty$. In this way, you avoid doing the complicated algebra of computing the RHS and reduce the chance of making mistakes.

Comment: @achillehui multiplying $x^2$ in what?

Comment: I mean $$
x^2\left( \frac{14}{x(x+14)}+\cdots+\frac{14}{(x+28)(x+42)}\right)
= x^2\left(\frac{a(x^2+42x+147)}{x(x+b)(x+c)(x+d)}\right)
$$
Taking limit of both side, you get $14 + 14 + 14 + 14 + 14 = a \implies a = 70$